# cant log in to phpmy admin after enabling innodb

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install magento into a waamp localhost since magento is an e commerce framework it uses innodb it is not enabled by default so I had enabled it by editing my.ini file in waamp this had solved innodb problem and the installer has recognized the innodb support but after this change I am not able to log into my phpmy admin account I am getting #2002 cannot log in to my SQL server I have even tried changing config.inc.php localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. InnoDB in wamp is enabled by default. Maybe there is something in your `my.ini` you've been edited and affect the settings. You should have a backup for that.

Comment: Restore your old `my.ini` and show us the error message you get when you install magento.

Comment: Thanks for that I have restored the old my.ini file ,but when I am installing magento in the validation the installer is saying that database server doesn't support InnoDB storage engine . I am using wamp 2.4

Comment: Check if you can access the database using the mysql command line